# Match string that starts with 9 digits and possibly ends with string

Tags: php, regex

I am basically trying to match a 10 character ISBN, so far I am able to match any string that is 10 characters long but it is not accurate at identifying the string as an ISBN

A 10 character long isbn can have 9 starting digits and end with a letter or have 10-digits,
e.g.

0273737025

027373702X

If the final character is a letter it will always be `X`

**what I have so far**

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]{10,10}
```

this regex will be able to extract an isbn from a string like

```
"asjdh - asd a -  dsa- 0273737025"  = 0273737025
```

but will also extract anything else that is 10 or more characters long

```
"asjdh - asd a -  dsa- myveryearly"  = myveryearl
```

Is there a regular expression that can meet these requirements?

Comment: "string" can contain numbers and other characters.  You should specify "letters" or something like that instead, e.g. "If the final character is a letter..."

Comment: ISBN's have check digits, you don't have to reinvent the wheel here

Comment: @Dagon That has nothing to do with the question

Comment: *"but it is not accurate at identifying the string as an ISBN"* that's exactly what the check digits are for

Comment: @Dagon by that I mean it can detect ANY 10 character long word.

Comment: with out using the ISBN check digits what every you try you will end up with an arbitrary sting of 10 digits with out knowing it is or is not an ISBN

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\d{9}(?:\d|X)
```

This is 9 digits followed by either a digit or 'X'.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
[0-9]{9}[xX0-9]
```

Or a more concise form:

```
\d{9}[xX\d]
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use a lookbehind to prevent finding 9 digits that were preceded by more digits.

```
(?<!\d)\d{9}[\dxX]
```